# Delete a version from a private PodSpecs repository?

Tags: cocoapods

While creating and publishing my Pod to a private PodSpecs repository, I published several test versions. How can I delete unwanted versions from my private PodSpecs repo?

Note: I am able to delete from the Cocoapods main trunk using the following command:

```
$ pod trunk delete RPUpdatingLabelFramework 1.16
```

I am looking for a similar command to delete from my private specs repo.

Comment: Ok, I found some help here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8176
However the solution here is to manually delete the directories for each version. I am looking for a pod command to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git commands are the only way to do it. There is not a pod command. See the docs at https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#group_repos

Feel free to send a PR to CocoaPods to add such a command.